# difficulty understanding signed not

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I'm having trouble understanding why c equals -61 on the following program:

```
   main() {
       unsigned int a = 60;     // 60 = 0011 1100   
       unsigned int b = 13;     // 13 = 0000 1101
       int c = 0;           
       c = ~a;          //-61 = 1100 0011
       printf("Line 4 - Value of c is %d\n", c );
   }
```

I do understand how the NOT operator works on 0011 1100 (the solution being 1100 0011). But I'm not sure why the decimal number is increased by 1. Is this some sort of type conversion from unsigned int (from a) into signed int (from c) ?

Comment: This is how two's complement notation works.

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: `11111111` is `-1`, `00000000` is `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Conversion from a positive to a negative number in twos complement (the standard signed format) constitutes a bitwise inversion, and adding one.

Note that for simplicity I am using a single signed byte.

```
So if 60 = 0011 1100
Then c   = 1100 0011 + 1
         = 1100 0100
```

And for a signed byte, the most significant bit is negative,
so

```
c = -128 + 64 + 4 = -60
```

You need to add 1 to account for the fact that the most significant bit is -128, while the largest positive number is 0111 1111 = 127. All negative numbers have a 1 for -128 which needs to be offset.

This is easy to see when you look at converting 0 to -0. Invert 00000000 and you get 11111111 and adding one gets you back to 00000000. Do the same with 1 to -1 and you get 11111111 - the largest possible negative number.

Comment: Nice answer. Twos-complement may seem as a complex and odd way of dealing with a signed number, but actually it is a very clever encoding that simplifies how a CPU is designed. It allows a simple unsigned binary adder circuit to work regardless of the sign of the added quantities, and eliminates the ambiguity of having both a positive or negative zero value.

Comment: could you clarify me a couple of things:
1) I do understand how to do 2's compliment, but why are we doing it? In what way is 2's compliment connected to a NOT operator?
2) I understand where these numbers come from:  c = -128 + 64 + 4 = -60, but the answer is c = -61. Where does that substraction (or addition of a -1) comes from?

Comment: So the reason that c is -61 and not -60 is because the NOT operator doesn't actually convert from positive to negative, it merely flips the bits. This is only half of the process to get from 60 to -60, the other half being adding 1 after flipping the bits.

So c = ~a + 1 is how you would 'manually' do twos complement conversion, but c = -1*a will do it for you under the hood.